# How can I connect to an external SQL database using Blazor without using packages (like Entity Framework)

Tags: sql, sql-server, razor, blazor-server-side

I'm not even sure if this is possible but Google has been unable to help me. It may just be because Blazor is so new. Anyway, I've got a premade database and I want to connect to it directly like how you can open a connection, run some SQL, then close a connection in ASP.NET. I, unfortunately, can't just make a new database using code-first as most tutorials tell you to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options that spring to mind is the Entity Framework Core (Database First) or Dapper.

I'm actually connecting to an existing database using Dapper in my Blazor projects and there are better Dapper examples/tutorials available however the below is a basic example.

https://github.com/DotNetDublin/BlazorServerSide/tree/main/BlazorServerSide

If you don't want to use either Entity Framework or Dapper you can use ADO.NET.

The below tutorial is for MVC however the code for interacting with the database would be the same. See StudentDataAccessLayer.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-using-asp-net-core-and-ado-net/

Comment: Thanks for the response! For some reason I totally missed a few errors in my post. I’m looking to do this without the help of EF or Dapper.  If that’s even possible

Comment: I've updated my answer to include ADO.Net

Comment: That’s exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

use the ef command  Scaffold-DbContext